# Switch to power 1 device from two different AC power sources

Tags: wiring, multiway-switch

I am trying to optimise workflow in my workshop and recently acquired a Master and Slave Auto Power-Off switch that turns on my workshop vacuum automatically when my power tool is switched on. The switch is shown on page 7 of this catalogue: https://www.smjuk.com/assets/Uploads/Cordset-Catalogue.pdf

The issue is that this no longer allows to use the vacuum standalone (for workshop cleaning) without fiddling with plugs/connecting/reconnecting them.
At the moment (to use the vac on its own) I have to unplug the vacuum from the master/slave switch and plug it to mains directly, do the cleaning bit and then unplug from mains and plug back to master/slave switch. It feels like a problem which must have been solved by many people before.

I am looking for a switch/solution which can allow to do the following:

**Condition 1**: vacuum connected via master/slave switch and comes on when a power tool connected to master is switched on

**Condition 2**: vacuum comes on on its own (without power tool)
- so it can be used to clean workshop

**Condition 3** (optional/nice to have): everything is OFF

I found [something](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/111503273813) which looks like it may do the job but it cost too much.

For now I have come up with a DIY solution using 2-Way light switch which looks like this

[image: Master-Slave Switch and Vacuum]

Based on the above - I have two questions

1. Is there an existing commercial (consumer friendly) solution to the above?

   - Ideally priced under $10
2. Are there any obvious issues with the solution shown on my drawing?

Comment: what is the minimum wattage on the master plug that activates the slave plug? You could add a small load like a light there in parallel to turn it on.

Comment: Assuming your vacuum's primary purpose is to vacuum miter saw dust then you could wire up a switch-controlled outlet, mount the switch in a convenient location, and make a habit out of turning it on/off when using the miter saw.

Comment: @ratchetfreak
Not sure about minimum wattage, it is not stated. I do not have tools using less than 100W.

MonkeyZeus
This vacuum is used with many tools in my workshop via DIY plug-it type thingy at the end of the vacuum hose. Here is an [example](https://youtu.be/bL4s25WfsSA?t=383). 
Mine is not Festool but the functionality is the same. Single switch won't do in my case due to several tools using the vacuum.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Answer (score 1):

### A heater

You're talking about using the vacuum with tools (plural).  So obviously, you're coming off the "master" socket with an extension lead to plug all your tools into.

So, plug in a heater too - or any other dummy load.  Turn the heater on, and the vac comes on.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Not going to work in my case unfortunately. The extension lead (where I plug tools or the dummy  load you suggested) is attached to the vac hose and terminates about 5cm from the vacuum hose end/nozzle. I would have to drag a long cable (of the dummy load) next  to the vacuum hose while using it for cleaning. Have a look at 6:30 in this [video](https://youtu.be/bL4s25WfsSA?t=383), it may give you better idea what the tool end of plug-it/power lead arrangement looks like.

Comment: Actually, this has been pointed out to me that this solution may work if I plugged a dummy load not directly to Master socket but via multi-way extension block connected to Master socket and also plugged tools extension lead to the same extension block.
Brilliant. Thank you.
Would you mind updating your answer to add these details, to make it clearer for anyone else searching for similar solution.